# Hive: no result display

Tags: hadoop, hive

After I run:

```
hive> select * from bxdataset where  yearofpublication = "2002";
```

The result is :

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   
HDFS Read: 9491 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS

Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

OK

Time taken: 9.651 seconds
```

So there is no any result display. But I'm pretty sure that there exits at least one row which yearofpublication is 2002. And the data type is STRING.

Comment: So the issue might be your table is not loaded correctly or yearofpublication has not have this value.
You can try "select * from bxdataset;" and see if everything is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your yearofpublication data by running simple query.

```
select yearofpublication from bxdataset limit 10
```

If you see your data in output ,then you can try something like below

```
select * from bxdataset where  yearofpublication like "%2002%";
```